# Android SDK 18.0.0 causing Eclipse Errors

Tags: android

I cannot open my eclipse projects with the new SDK(18.0.0)
I get Java errors, and I know its the SDK because I am able to use eclipse without updating, but the old SDK vanished and I am forced to update to continue with my app.

Here are the errors
OnStartup:

An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling". java.lang.NullPointerException

When closing

Problems occurred while closing java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It's happening to me too. I've updated the ADT to version 18 and I can't work anymore -_-

Answer (score 1):

Do not delete all the full .metadata

- Backup .metadata
- delete only .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.project
- restart eclipse

Observation : the projects folders are created

Further - if you are using svn/git/hg have code repository links it would be destroyed, so to reinstate

- close eclipse
- copy relevant projects from backup to merge with current projects in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.project
- restart eclipse

Downfall - sporadic fail error may occur (sync or something) - harmless

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the ADT-Plugin?

Comment: I don't think I'm using it. I just went (in eclipse) Help > Install New Software and pasted the URL. All of the APIs are up to date and installed. However before I updated it to 18.0.0 eclipse didn't recognise any Android terms and wouldn't let me import them. After I installed 18.0.0 I couldn't open the project without getting numerous pop-up errors

Comment: If you are developing in eclipse for an android application you are using the ADT-Plugin. Please go to Help > Install new Software > click the link already installed. And if the Version of the Android Plugins is lower than 18 you have to select them all and update them.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by closing all the projects in the workspace and opening only those that I need. I haven't found out the real reason, but at least I can work on.